# Is there a limitation of SESSION in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I wrote a code for a login-form which uses the Session-tag to deliver the user data to other pages.
But if I am access the Session from a other page the Session is empty.

The login-form is under ../Pages/Login/Login.php and the reading page is under ../Pages/School/index.php.
Could there be an limitation of the Session, because the reading page is in a other folder?

On each page the Session is started using `session_start()` on the start of the page.

Comment: What kind of limitations are you talking about? Max data? Datatypes?

Comment: Like passing the Session to other pages (inside one Domain)

Comment: Have you done session_start(); on the other pages? IF you want to get items you have to do that on every page

Comment: Got it...Do not know the mistake